# Camel Bindy giving Undesolved Dependency error on Talend ESB Karaf

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, bindy

I've a peculiar issue with trying to use a route which uses Bindy.

```
blueprint.core - 1.8.3 | Unable to start blueprint container for bundle xxxx.yyyy/0.1.0 due to unresolved dependencies [(&(dataformat=bindy)(objectClass=org.apache.camel.spi.DataFormatResolver))]
```

Having checked the Karaf Webconsole, camel-bindy module is exporting

```
Service ID 636 Types: org.apache.camel.spi.DataFormatResolver
```

so I don't understand why this isn't being detected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install camel-bindy on you container. Your bundle depends on service 
**org.apache.camel.spi.DataFormatResolver** whit a service property **dataformat=bindy**.
Service 636 is not being detected, because is not registering this property whit value **bindy**

Comment: The service is exporting bindy-fixed and bindy-csv etc, not just plain bindy. What I now need to do is figure out why my route is dependant on "bindy" only...